# How to debug frequent "connection reset by peer"

Tags: networking, tcp

Recently I started to have very frequent "connection reset by peer" on calls to an external provider. My application (client) is a Go application, doing some simple POST to an external provider over HTTPS

**Some context:**

- Go client application is running on docker.
- The "connection reset by peer" is frequent, but erratic.
- Provider says nothing is wrong on their end. Ok, `RST`
  can come from anywhere in between us.

**The host instance ifconfig:**

```
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr [REDACTED]
          inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:172.17.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr [REDACTED]
          inet addr:10.208.19.134  Bcast:10.208.19.255  Mask:255.255.255.128
          inet6 addr: fe80::8d:fdff:fe90:f410/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:9001  Metric:1
          RX packets:37685240 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:37927624 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:13408927179 (12.4 GiB)  TX bytes:14057395581 (13.0 GiB)
```

**I tried:**

- Ran `tcpdump -vv -i eth0 -s 65535 -n dst host [[PROVIDER IP]] -w capture.cap &` on host instance (EC2)
- Opened capture with Wireshark an looked for `tcp.flags.reset==1`

Couldn't find anything. And am sure there were connection reset by peer during the capture (as we have logging in place). All I wanted to understand is where the `RST` is coming from (if that is possible).

So, what options do I have to look for the root cause of all these sudden errors?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when tried to connect to remote host via VPN.
I got an error:

```
OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer in connection <HOST>:<PORT>
```

In my case (on Fedora 36) I decreased MTU from 1500 (default) to 1400.

```
sudo ifconfig ppp0 mtu 1400 up
```

Answer (score 0):

To prove that the packets originate outside, try adding this to your router:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -i eth0 -p tcp --tcp-flags RST RST -j DROP
```

Be aware that RST packets are needed in normal operation and this could quickly hog your resources, so limit it to a particular `--sport`, even for testing, unless the router is used very lightly and only leave it in place for this test.

Replace FORWARD with INPUT if you are testing and filtering on a single machine. Replace eth0 with your actual internet connection.

For rudimentary confirmation, you can issue `iptables -nvL | grep spt` and see how the number at the start increased.

Comment: what do you mean `adding this to your router `? Are you considering the host EC2 instance the router. When a packet reaches the host heading to the docker, does it hit `FORWARD`, is that it?

Answer (score 0):

Attempt to change your MTU to 1500 rather than 9001. If the traffic is going out to the internet, it’s getting fragmented. It's doesn't make sense to have jumbo frame setting on that adapter.

Try

> sudo ifconfig eth0 mtu 1500 up